# R plot: Moving non-numeric axis values along the axis

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering if I could **shift the non-numeric values** (e.g., "**Trivial**" **see R code below**) **up** on my **axis on side 4** such that each non-numeric value be exactly ***positioned between*** the **current tickmarks (I need to keep the current tickmarks)** on this particular axis?

**Note:** you see I have placed `" "` for the highest non-numeric axis value, this is because I don't need it (may be there is way that `" "` could be deleted).

Here is **the R code:**

```
curve(dnorm(x),-3,3,bty="n")
axis(side=4,at = c(0,.1, .2, .3,.4),labels = c("Trivial", "Anecdotal", "Substantial","Strong", " "),las=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them exactly between the tick marks, it may be easiest to put specify their positions exactly with a second call to `axis` to plot the labels.

```
curve(dnorm(x), -3, 3, bty = "n")
axis(side = 4, at = c(0, .1, .2, .3, .4), 
     labels = FALSE)                  # don't generate labels

axis(side = 4, 
     at = c(0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35),  # put the labels half-way between
     labels = c("Trivial", "Anecdotal", "Substantial","Strong"),
     tick = FALSE,                    # don't plot the tick marks
     las = 1)
```

Comment: thanks, but my fear is that in my Shiny App, this using of Axis twice can show itself making this axis appear darker in color or thicker in size?

Comment: @parvinkarimi from the `axis` help page, `tick` is "a logical value specifying whether tickmarks and an axis line should be drawn."  When it's FALSE, it won't draw the line again.  Alternatively, their is a color argument, which could be set to "transparent."